# iOS17 Workout Scheduler shared between iPhone and Apple Watch

Tags: apple-watch, ios17

Is there anyway to share a WorkoutScheduler https://developer.apple.com/documentation/workoutkit/workoutscheduler across an iPhone and watch app? If I create a scheduler on the phone app the watch app can't see it and creates its own separate schedule. I'm using WorkoutScheduler.shared.scheduledWorkouts but end up with two identical sections at the top of the workout app

I'm using WorkoutScheduler.shared.scheduledWorkouts but end up with two identical sections at the top of the workout app rather than a shared one